# Is it possible to select alle columns from table, except one (eg. ID)?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using a third party application which has an absurd number of columns per table. When I select data, often I need all columns except the ID. Or all columns except ID and DateCreated.

Using the sys.columns it's possible to find out which columns are available in a table. How can I use this information to create statements? What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you include all the columns and just ignore the fact you have the ID in the data as well?

Comment: You'll need to supply all of the columns apart from that one in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: If you're okay writing a query in SSMS, simply open the database, scroll down to the table you're looking at, click the little + icon next to it, and drag the "Columns" folder to your query window. That will get you a list of all columns in that table. Then you can simply remove the column you do not need.

Comment: @Rob Anthony: I would like to use an except to find double data. In the ID there is always a unique number, so when I use that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @SchmitzIT: I know, this is what I do now. And I am lazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will select all columns for any table except the primary key column of the table and the column names DateCreated.

```
SELECT
'SELECT '+
SUBSTRING(LIST,1,LEN(LIST)-1)
+' FROM [Person].[Address]'
FROM
(
SELECT
    '['+COL.COLUMN_NAME+'],'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COL
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                CON.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
                USG.TABLE_SCHEMA,
                USG.TABLE_NAME,
                USG.COLUMN_NAME,
                CON.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                USG.TABLE_CATALOG
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE USG
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CON
                    ON USG.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CON.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        )Q
            ON COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = Q.TABLE_SCHEMA
                AND COL.TABLE_NAME = Q.TABLE_NAME 
                AND COL.TABLE_CATALOG = Q.TABLE_CATALOG
                AND COL.COLUMN_NAME = Q.COLUMN_NAME
        WHERE COL.TABLE_SCHEMA ='Person'
            AND COL.TABLE_NAME = 'Address'
            AND 
            (
                Q.CONSTRAINT_TYPE <> 'PRIMARY KEY'
                OR
                COL.COLUMN_NAME <> 'DateCreated'
            )
            FOR XML PATH(''))L(LIST)
```

Replace the string Person with your schema and Address With you table name

Comment: Works like a charm! I'll see how to use this as efficient as possible and will post that in this question later on.

Answer (score 0):

try using dynamic Query:

```
    DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + Column_Name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE Table_name='Table1'
    And Column_Name!='ID'

    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @Query = 'SELECT '+ @Names + ' INTO Table2 FROM Table1'

    exec (@Query)


    SELECT * from Table2
```

Comment: This works. I also like your "into" addition. The mentioned ID's are FK's, so Jayasurya Satheesh answer fits better. Thanks for thinking with me though!